# Calculating Vo in the following problem

Tags: resistors, diodes, basic, homework

I'm sorry I'm totally new to electronics and I get confused of what Vo is in such problems and how to calculate it so can someone explain what Vo is and how to calculate it [image]

Comment: What have you tried already? Where are you stuck? What model for the diode you have been instructed to use?

Comment: I don't know what Vo is all about tbh like what does it mean ?

Answer (score 1):

> I get confused of what Vo is in such problems and how to calculate it

That's fine. This way of drawing schematics might be new to you so at first it might be confusing.

So go back to this first.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbFNKi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Q: What is Vo?
Well, write KVL at the outermost mesh. They never lie to you. You'll find that Vo = VR2 - 2. Nothing more. In other words, you have to find first VR2 - then Vo (we call it *output potential*) will be under that voltage by 2V. If, say, V2 = 0 (i.e. R2 was connected between Vo and ground) then Vo is just VR2.

Answer (score 0):

V<sub>O</sub> is the *output* voltage.

Since this is homework we won't give you a direct answer but will guide you through the problem as you edit details into your question. Use the edit link below your question.

First hint: Remove the Si diode and replace it with a wire link. Can you work out V<sub>O</sub> now?

Comment: It would be like a branch with the 4.7K R as  second branch

Comment: The problem is I don't understand what an output voltage is ( it's not a homework but I'm preparing for a test )